# Doing a for-each in XSLT for certain nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

Hi guys I have a problem here, am completely new to XSLT and it's driving me a bit crazy, as I'm not familiar with the syntax, however the logic seems pretty simple.

So I have an xml of format:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>value1</C>
    <D>amount1</D>
  </B>
</A>
<A>
  <B>
    <C>value2</C>
    <D>amount2</D>
  </B>
</A>
```

In this case I want to do a for each loop that returns the value of every node C of A/B ONLY WHEN Node D is a certain value. So for example, you could say

for-each A/B, return c, where d = "amount1"

Anyone help out with what the XSLT would be for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="A/B[D='amount1']">
     <xsl:value-of select="C" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note, this assumed you are currently positioned on the parent element of all the **A** elements.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can skip `xsl:for-each` and use

```
<xsl:copy-of select="root/A/B[D[.='amount1']]/C"/>
```

I have added a `root` tag in your input for testing.

Comment: I have used `copy-of` instead of `value-of` in case there are many matches